# change text-font size of whole page content

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way in javascript/css that i can change text size of all the labels, headings, paragraphs etc on a single click and without explicitly getting element's id and then changing its font size.

what i am doing right now is that i get element's id through javascript and change its font size explicitly. To get a clear picture of what i am doing check this [link](http://www.simon.kaulius.com/dynamically_change_text_javascript.htm) or check the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changemysize(myvalue) {
    var div = document.getElementById("mymain");
    div.style.fontSize = myvalue + "px";   
}
</script>
```

HTML code

```html
Choose a text size:
<font size="2"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changemysize(16);">A</a></font>
<font size="4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changemysize(20);">A</a></font>
<font size="5"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changemysize(25);">A</a></font>
<div id="mymain">
Only this text gets affected
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an id to the `body` tag and then go ahead and change it's font size with JavaScript. This will change the font size for every element inside your webpage! It is as simple as that!

Comment: or just simply style the body

Comment: No need to ID the body, just use `document.body`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rem`, which is better than `em` in some places because `em` cascades and `rem` does not.

With all lengths are specified in `rem`, you can adjust the sizes by change the font-size of the `<html>` element.

See also: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: Very handy tip! Shame it requires IE9 plus, because `ems` can be both a blessing and a curse. I'll probably use `rem` from now on if I don't care about older IEs.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the font of a element and its children recursively to "force" it all to change:

```
function changeFont(element){
    element.setAttribute("style",element.getAttribute("style")+";font-family: Courier New");
    for(var i=0; i < element.children.length; i++){
        changeFont(element.children[i]);
    }
}
changeFont(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
```

Alternatively you can use the `style` atribute of the element as object:

```
function changeFont(element){
    element.style.fontFamily="Courier New";
    for(var i=0; i < element.children.length; i++){
        changeFont(element.children[i]);
    }
}
changeFont(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `ems` as a measure for setting font sizes. That way, with 1 tag, you can adjust the font sizes of every element *relatively*, instead of specifying specific sizes. Example:

```
body {
  font-size: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

p.large {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Then you could apply a class to the body, like so

```
body.enlarged {
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Which would scale the font size of *all* elements respectively. The javascript code would go something like this:

```
document.body.classList.add('enlarged');
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/bW9fM/1/

Comment: Why mix regular js with jquery?

Comment: @BramVanroy jQuery is used for the demo to bind the handler; it is not part of the question (he's bound his own handler, albiet in a poor way) the question was not tagged with jQuery therefore I didn't use jQuery's `.addClass()`. Using a library doesn't mean you can't use raw JS. If it makes your life better, here's a [pure js version](http://jsfiddle.net/bW9fM/1/), and a [jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/bW9fM/2/).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320012/740639)

```js
// iterate over the children of an element, and the element itself
// and excute a callback function, passing in the elements
function mapElement(element, callback){
    callback(element);    
    for(var i=0; i < element.children.length; i++){
        callback(element.children[i]);
    }
}

mapElement(
    document.querySelector('body'), 
    (e) => { 
        e.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
        e.style.fontSize = '12pt'; 
    }
);
```