# Resizing Letters Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to get the font size to change when you click on the different sized letters that are on the right. How do I go about commanding the site to do that using javascript? Here is the code I have so far:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<div> 
 <font size="2"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changemysize(16);">A</a></font>
 <font size="4"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changemysize(20);">A</a></font>
 <font size="5"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changemysize(25);">A</a></font>

</div>

<div id="callout" class="medium">
    <ul id="controls">
        <li id="small">A</li>
        <li id="medium">A</li>
        <li id="large">A</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mymain">
         <h1>Header</h1>

         <h2>Subheader</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ne periculis definiebas, habeo gloriatur has id. Ius ad ubique animal, eum recteque electram explicari no, sed in nostrum adipiscing. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pri ne periculis definiebas, habeo gloriatur has id.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 75%;"><a href="../resize.zip">Download the files (resize.zip)</a>

</p>

<script src="resize.js"></script> 

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function changemysize(myvalue) {
    var div = document.getElementById("mymain");
    div.style.fontSize = myvalue + "px";
}
```

Comment: "How do I go about..." is usually not a good question. We expect that you try first, then come back with your code, a live demo and people might help.

Comment: @elclanrs well maybe there's some good stuff in "resize.js" :)

Comment: There isn't anything in resize.js that is of any use.

Comment: What's `resize.js`?  What do you need help with?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: resize.js is just a file with instructions on what I need to do. On the page, there is a small "A", medium "A", and a large "A". I need the font size to change to small, medium, and large when you click on the "A".

Comment: @user2916725: Where are you stuck?  We're not going to do this for you.  What *exactly* do you need help with?

Comment: I've updates my original question to show what I've tried and I don't think it's close to working.

Comment: @user2916725: There's no element with an id of `'mymain'`.

Comment: Do I put that in the <div>? What would be an example of the code?

Comment: @user2916725:  You need to have your `changemysize` function select an element that exists in your page.  You can wrap the elements you want resized in a `<div id="mymain">` or you can change your `document.getElementById("mymain")` to select an id that exists (or use other `document.getElementByXXX` functions).

Comment: Can you give me a more clearer example of what the code would look like?

Comment: @user2916725: What part of my suggestion(s) confused you?

Comment: I just don't know what I need to write to get the function to select the right element.

Comment: @user2916725: What element(s) do you want to resize?  My 1st suggestion was just to add another `<div>` to the page.  Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wfT39/

Comment: I updated my original post to something like what you said, and it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: @user2916725: What did you edit in the post?

Comment: I changed the <div> to look like what you referenced above.

Comment: @user2916725: You didn't change anything.  I added a `<div id="mymain">` to the HTML.  Check the example again: http://jsfiddle.net/wfT39/

Comment: Sorry! I just updated it again. I then put what you had as the javascript in the resize.js file. It still isn't changing the font size.

Comment: @user2916725: Do you see any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: I just posted my javascript. Do I need to have the <script>, </script>?

Comment: @user2916725: If it's in the HTML file, yes.  If it's in its own `.js` file, no.

Comment: I have updated everything and it still isn't working properly. Why?

Comment: @user2916725: How are you adding that JavaScript to the page?

Comment: I thought I was linking it to that page in the HTML, no?

Comment: @user2916725: Not in the code currently shown in the question.

Comment: I updated it again and now it is linked, right? It still isn't working.

Comment: Do you know how to open the JS console?  Check for errors.

Comment: What do you mean open the JS console?

Comment: @user2916725: What browser are you using?  They all have built-in tools to help developers.  The console will show any error/warning messages from JavaScript.

Comment: It says there is errors with the <div> with the different font sizes and the link to the resize.js file.

Comment: @user2916725: What is the *exact* message?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Define a class in your css file for enlarged fontsize.
- Call a function on your li's onclick
- Let the function add/remove respective class for ur html body `document.body.classList.add('nameOfTheClassWithFontSize');`

Ref: [change text-font size of whole page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460990/change-text-font-size-of-whole-page-content)

Comment: Please try to follow the steps, use jsfiddle.net. If that dint help, please check the reference I shared. I'm sure you'll find your answer.

Comment: you are getting the element by document.getElementById("mymain");
But there isn't any html element with that id.

Answer (score 0):

For your HTML using jQuery:
**$('body').css('font-size', '12px');**

You can pass size you want for increasing/decreasing and so on.